# How to import a python file with relative path dependency using Jenkins bash shell script?

Tags: python, jenkins

I have a python script for interacting with aws secrets manager (aws_secrets) that I am calling in the program_to_run.py file.

Inside of program_to_run.py I have
from aws_secrets import aws_read_secrets

In pycharm it finds this successfully, below is the file structure.

```
+-- aws_secrets
|   +-- aws_secrets2.py
+-- folder
|   +-- program_to_run.py
```

I am trying to run program_to_run.py in Jenkins using a shell script.

python3 root/folder/program_to_run.py

But when I run it I get this

ImportError: cannot import name 'aws_secrets2' from 'aws_secrets' (/home/jenkins-agent/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aws_secrets/**init**.py)

So my question is, how do I correctly call aws_secrets2.py from program_to_run.py using a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that Jenkins seems to have trouble referencing packages if they were installed on the machine from outside (as opposed to within Jenkins). So try adding these two lines to the pipeline before calling `python3 root/folder/program_to_run.py`

```
pip uninstall aws-secrets
pip install aws-secrets
```